# How do I find my OneNote notebooks so I can back them up before doing a complete system wipe?

Tags: windows, backup, sync, microsoft-onenote

Okay so there are many issues with this. I've worked mostly offline recently for OneNote, so nothing I synced to the web. I use the desktop app for the program. Under X account, when I try to log in to sync it all on the web it says there is no account for x account (which there should be).

OneDrive has some of my notebooks. but they are not up-to-date and it won't sync. I've tried going to C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote<ver>, but the only things in there are a backup folder that's empty, a cache folder with like four files, three that are .bin (4kb), a header file, and a tmp folder (empty).

I hope that's enough information to help me. I need to find my up-to-date notebooks so I can back them up, wipe my system completely and reinstall. Doing a system restore and keeping my files is not an option.

Also, won't be using that account anymore so getting it to work isn't a concern unless it gets me to where they can be backed up.

Comment: I got it to sync the notebooks on the web. but not in the onedrive. and still nothing in the appdata folder.   was a problem with internet explorer accepting cookies. and javascript

Comment: They should be here:   C:\Users\usernameDesktop\ABC Documents\MSOffice\OneNote  or a similar location that should be familiar to you (alongside Word and Excel Folders).  That is where I stored mine.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/back-up-notes-f58b34b0-611d-435e-87fa-7942a1767af4

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, the Backup folder for your notebooks is located at

**C:\Users*user name*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote*version*\Backup.**

Or you can check the default location for backup files by the following steps

Click File > Options > Save & Backup.

Under Save, in the Paths list, click Backup Folder, and this is the location of the folder where OneNote to store backup files.